# Hide popup window if click out his area

Tags: javascript, html

I have my simple popup window with pure JS:

```
function popup()
{
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
}
function popup_close()
{
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';
}
```

look full code: https://jsfiddle.net/u7vxoe48/

I want add function to close this popup window if i click out of popup_content area, but dont know how, i'm try add onclick function to parent of popup_content, but clicking in popup_content also trigger onclick function of parent...

No JQuery, only pure JS

Comment: Many more examples in jQuery if you just search google

Comment: @mplungjan need pure JS only

Comment: So see the method in the duplicate post. Just look at the event.target id or tagname